# Как с помощью php задать css-стиль для конкретной страницы?

Tags: php, css, joomla

Всем привет.
Как в Joomla задать с помощью php в основном файле шаблона index.php свой css стиль для конкретной страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Это будет работать не только в Joomla.

```
  <style>
    .ololo { color: red; } /* правило по умолчанию */
    #about .ololo { color: green; } /* работает только на странице about.php */
  </style?
</head>
<body id="<?= basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']), '.php') ?>">
  <div class="ololo">
  …
```

Здесь в ID тега боди попадает [имя скрипта](http://php.net/basename) без пути и расширения. Мы можем использовать это имя для того, чтобы указать правило CSS для конкретной страницы. Я выбрал именно тег body, т.к. он является родителем всех отображаемых элементов, а значит его класс/айди можно добавить к любому правилу CSS.

Comment: А если нужно на конкретной странице изменить вид активной ссылки, к примеру? Можете показать на примере страницы `http://site.com/test.php`?

Comment: @Равиль, Извините, не понял дополнительного вопроса! Без разницы какой стиль менять. Ваша цель задать *разное* представление одних и тех же элементов на разных страницах. Значит надо на страницах изменить что-то, что можно включить в цепочку селекторов. Я предлагаю менять класс тега body, т.к. его можно указать префиксом к *любому* правилу.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Просто я не понял, как в коде указать, что именно для /test.php будет применён другой класс.

Comment: Судя по отсутствию оценки, вы и сейчас не понимаете :)
Смотрите строку с <body>. Там для каждого скрипта назначается свой id. Понятно, что это только демонстрация техники и вы можете id заменить на class, а вместо SCRIPT_FILENAME использовать что-то более подходящее для вашего случая.

Comment: Я честно пытался поставить оценку, но мне пишут, что не могу.
Всё равно спасибо.)